# Why is LINQ not purely functional?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, functional-programming

So, why exactly is LINQ not considered purely functional?

Is it because side effects can occur? Or is it maybe because it exists in an imperative environment?

Comment: `Is it because side effects can occur?`. Yes.

Comment: @Oded Is that the only reason?

Comment: It is enough. No need for more.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. It can be (and has been) answered in a way that is "supported by facts, references, or specific expertise", and is not likely to solicit debate, arguments, whatever. Beginner questions that seem obvious **are not bad questions simply because they are obvious**. The fact that they can be immediately and trivially answered by anyone who knows anything about the field means we should answer them quickly and then forget about them, not close them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LINQ is not a purely functional programming model as it permits side effects, is thus not [referentially-transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29), which is a common definition of ["purely functional"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming#Pure_functions).